# sed command to update the urls from a given sql file and output to another using a function under bash_aliases

Tags: macos, sed

I have an sql file that needs to be updated, in this case, a url. Then the output should be another sql file. I actually made my function work using the command line but wouldn't work under .bash_aliases

Here's the command line that worked

```
LC_CTYPE=C sed -n 's#http://www.domain.com#http://localhost/domain#g'  $domain.sql > $domain.edited.sql;
```

Here's the function on my .bash_aliases file

```
dbupdate() { LC_CTYPE=C sed -n 's#$1#$2#g'  $3.sql > $3.edited.sql; }
```

So when I run this dbupdate function it will produce the domain.edited.sql file but doesn't contain anything. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "un-quote" the script arguments $1 $2

```
dbupdate() { LC_CTYPE=C sed 's#'$1'#'$2'#g'  $3.sql > $3.edited.sql; }
```

Comment: Thanks but the result is the same. It created the file but it doesn't contain anything. Actually, the command I used above previously worked. I don't know why all of a sudden it didn't.

Comment: Sorry for this very late reply. I somehow oversaw your comment. You were right on my solution still not working. The reason however lied on the "-n" option, which is unnecessary. It means disable printing the patter space. You 'p' option at the end precisely undoes that. So, the simples option is just removing option -n. You still need the arguments to be outside of the single quotes if you want the shell to substitute them for their value -otherwise they would be taken literally by sed as the regexs to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I just add the "p" flag. Here's the function I used

```
dbupdate() { LC_CTYPE=C sed -n 's#'$1'#'$2'#gp'  $3.sql > $3.edited.sql; }
```

Thanks @MASL for your help.